# math calculations in ruby

Tags: ruby, math

I have a standard formula for calculating loan amortization schedule.

Here is the formula:

```
(Px(i/12))/(1-(1+i/12)^-n)
```

Here is what I have in ruby:

```
p = BigDecimal('1000.0')
n = BigDecimal('12')
i = BigDecimal('3')

m = (p * (i/12))/(1-(1+i/12) ** -n)
```

I'm getting a following error: in `**': wrong argument type BigDecimal (expected Fixnum) (TypeError)

I'm having hard time trying to play with Fixnun, Float and BigDecimal in ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n must be an integer per definition if you want to use `**` aka [`BigDecimal#power(n)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-2A-2A)

PS: I just looked up your formula on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator). Since n is the number of payments, it will be an integer by nature so just use a Fixnum for n - you won't get any troubles :)

Comment: You've never seen some of my payments.

Comment: hehe ok.. then we'll floor your number of payments :P

Answer (score 0):

Using floats :

```
>> p = 1000.0
=> 1000.0
>> n = 12.0
=> 12.0
>> i = 3.0
=> 3.0
>> (p*(i/12))/(1-(1+i/12)**-n)
=> 268.447577024146
```

Using BigDecimal :

```
>> p = BigDecimal('1000.0')
=> #<BigDecimal:1082c4760,'0.1E4',4(12)>
>> n = BigDecimal('12')
=> #<BigDecimal:1082c14c0,'0.12E2',4(8)>
>> i = BigDecimal('3')
=> #<BigDecimal:1082be2e8,'0.3E1',4(8)>
>> m = (p * (i/12))/(1-(1+i/12) ** -n.to_i)
=> #<BigDecimal:1082b4950,'0.2684475770 2414639639 7495957671 887300036E3',40(48)>
>> m.to_i
=> 268
```

It seems that the BigDecimal ** only takes a FixNum as the power part...
By putting the .0 at the end of the numbers it makes them all into floats. Works for me.

Comment: I choose BigDecimal because I thought BigDecimal is more accurate then float

Comment: it is.. especially if adding/subtracting prices. If you want to store values only, float is fine but if you want to do arithmetics you should switch to BigDecimals. Just try this: `0.3 - 0.2 - 0.1` or google for floating point arithmetic. Another option is to calculate in cents instead of dollars so you can always round up to the last cent and calculate with whole integers ;)

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated my post. It seems that the BigDecimal needs a FixNum as the power value... @sled is right. Calculate in cents, that is the best way of doing it.